# OAuth2 - Authorizing against another OAuth sever

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am building an OAuth server and understand the concept of the "Resource Owner Password Credentials" grant method. The user supplies a username and password and the grant_type is set to "password".

However, when the users authenticates using a social network such as Facebook, what grant_type should be specified and what is the suggested flow for handling this type of authentication?

The grant_type would be similar to password, but instead checking the username and password I would be checking the user_id returned from the social network.

I have checked the [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) but it does not mention this type of flow.

How should an OAuth server authorize against another OAuth server?

Answer (score 0):

There are different implementations about this. Most of the websites doesn't need any grant_type however, some of them are still using grant_type as password. When the user connects to facebook (installs your facebook app), if the user needs to be registered you can assign him/her a random password or you can still ask the user to register with password. So, the grant_type will be password still.

Comment: But is there a suggested flow for my app (as the Oauth server) authenticating a user using Facebook. Client->my oauth server-> facebook oauth?

Comment: I think it's optional. Since it is not specified, you can use `client->facebook_oauth->your_oauth_server`.